# Sort, taking into account a suffixed number

Tags: bash

I need to sort a list that I will later run a regex on. The list consists of a string concatenated with a number, so:

```
username10
username7
username9
```

I will later use with a regex to get the next, username11. The issue is that it's popping out of sort with username10 coming before username7, because 1 is less than 7.

I thought the k option would work for me (-k8n means the key is at position 8, sort numerically), but it doesn't alter the length of the list.

I'm also taking this list from stdin. I assume that is working because a simple test with that works.

Is there something I'm missing? I understand the issue (10 < 9 because 1 < 9), but not how to solve it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313280/sort-unix-alphabetically-then-numerically-not-working-as-i-intended

Comment: That does it - so what I was looking for was `sort -k1.9n` (starting at the 9th index). Bonus points to pull a variable out of a regex for the length, but I don't think I need that